# Is it possible to get the SQL statement together with the error returned by node-postgres?

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

I get errors that look like this from `node-postgres` (when calling its `client.query` method):

```
{ [Error: syntax error at or near "as"]
 severity: 'ERROR',
 code: '42601',
 position: '60',
 file: 'scan.l',
 line: '1044',
 routine: 'scanner_yyerror' } }
```

If I could see the offending SQL alongside the error message, it would make debugging a lot easier. Is it possible to get it somehow?

I realise that I can implement this manually (wrap `client.query` etc.), but what I'm interested in is whether `node-postgres` itself can be coerced into providing the SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code (https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/lib/client.js#L331), the `query` method returns a Query object. So you should be able to do something like this:

```
var query = client.query('SELECT $1::int AS number', ['1'], function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    var sql = query.text;
  }
}
```

(assuming your callback function is in the same scope as `query`).

<sub>Disclaimer: I've never used node-postgres.</sub>

Comment: Looks like this is my best and only option. Thanks. It's actually `query.text` for the SQL and `query.values` to get parameter values (no `.config`).

Comment: Fixed. I couldn't actually test it since I didn't have a server running.